# PDFMake conflicts with Underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, underscore.js-templating, pdfmake

While in the process of adding [HTML5 export functionality](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) to jQuery's dataTables I noticed that one of the required plugins [(PDFMake)](http://pdfmake.org/) conflicts with my current usage of underscore.js templating.

I was wondering if anyone else had encountered this issue or has any insight as to how to resolve this conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was a result of PDFMake also including underscore.js however at a lower version.

I was able to resolve this conflict by simply including the newer version of underscore after the inclusion of PDFMake.

This restored functionality for the rest of the app and didn't seem to effect PDFMake.

Comment: I had the same problem. It's related to https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/pull/443. This pull request solved it. Too bad that it's not yet committed...